# Set the correct currency form via Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello dear community,

I would like to bring all my values to the German currency format.  I can use the following function to retrieve all the data I want to change and only need to bring them to the correct format with a formula.

It will also retrieve data which is not a currency, that should be disregarded.

So
**Current English format:** **10.00€**
Should be changed to German format

Also only the full numbers should be displayed, so **not 10,00€ but 10€.**

Maybe someone has a simple solution, thanks.

```
function setTheRightFormula() {

 let getRangeFirstTable = overview.getRange(4, 3, 3, 3)
 let getRangeSecondTable = overview.getRange(9, 3, 3, 3)
 let getRangeThirdTable = overview.getRange(14, 3, 4, 5)

 var valuesFirstTable = getRangeFirstTable.getValues();
 var valuesSecondTable = getRangeSecondTable.getValues();
 var valuesThirdTable = getRangeThirdTable.getValues();

 valuesFirstTable.forEach(function(row) {
   row.forEach(function(col) {
     //Logger.log(col);
   });
 });
  valuesSecondTable.forEach(function(row) {
   row.forEach(function(col) {
     Logger.log(col);
   });
 });
  valuesThirdTable.forEach(function(row) {
   row.forEach(function(col) {
     Logger.log(col);
   });
 });
}
```

This is what the Console outputs.

```
11:48:33 PM Info    220.0
11:48:33 PM Info    14.5
11:48:33 PM Info    3190.0
11:48:33 PM Info    662.0
11:48:33 PM Info    14.5
11:48:33 PM Info    9599.0
11:48:33 PM Info    882.0
11:48:33 PM Info    
11:48:33 PM Info    12789.0
11:48:33 PM Info    9.0
11:48:33 PM Info    3190.0
11:48:33 PM Info    354.44444444444446
11:48:33 PM Info    53.0
11:48:33 PM Info    9599.0
11:48:33 PM Info    181.11320754716982
11:48:33 PM Info    62.0
11:48:33 PM Info    12789.0
11:48:33 PM Info    206.2741935483871
11:48:33 PM Info    9.0
11:48:33 PM Info    1200.0
11:48:33 PM Info    10800.0
11:48:33 PM Info    3190.0
11:48:33 PM Info    7610.0
11:48:33 PM Info    53.0
11:48:33 PM Info    1200.0
11:48:33 PM Info    63600.0
11:48:33 PM Info    9599.0
11:48:33 PM Info    54001.0
11:48:33 PM Info    13.25
11:48:33 PM Info    1200.0
11:48:33 PM Info    15900.0
11:48:33 PM Info    Ohne Berechnung
11:48:33 PM Info    15900.0
11:48:33 PM Info    75.25
11:48:33 PM Info    
11:48:33 PM Info    90300.0
11:48:33 PM Info    12789.0
11:48:33 PM Info    77511.0
```

Comment: For clarification: (1) Are you only interested in outputting values to the console, but not saving back to a Google Sheet? Or do you want to save to the sheet also? I was not sure what you meant by "_bring them to the correct format with a formula_".

Comment: And also (2) "_only the full numbers_" - What should happen to `14.5`? Should that be truncated to `14` or rounded? If it is to be rounded, then using which [rounding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)?